# Calling subclass method from other class - Android (java)

Tags: java, android, database, subclass, sqliteopenhelper

I have a working trivia game and am now trying to implement a highscores.  I created a subclass DatabaseHelper class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.  I am trying to call a method in the subclass DatabaseHelper from another class and am getting errors.  The classes won't compile so there is no LogCat output.  I have commented in the code the errors.

Code structure advice is appreciated as well!

Highscores.java

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
            //code
        }

        public boolean check(long score, int percentage) {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

Results.java

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;  //Error:  "DatabaseHelper cannot be resolved to a type."

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dh = new DatabaseHelper();  //Error:  "DatabaseHelper cannot be resolved to a type."
    }

    public void showResults() {

        if(dh.check(score, percentage) == true) {  //Error:  "DatabaseHelper cannot be resolved to a type."
      dh.insert(score, percentage);  //Error:  "DatabaseHelper cannot be resolved to a type."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing an import at the top of your Results.java

It should look something like import com.somepackage.DatabaseHelper;

Errors like this are typically either a typo in the class name or a missing import.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem. Is this the right approach?  Seems strange to just import a subclass from another class.

Comment: It's perfectly normal. Some IDEs will automatically import them for you too. There's keyboard shortcuts as well generally. In Eclipse on OSx for example, I hit command+shift+o and it fixes all of these errors.

Answer (score 6):

When you need a class outside of the class it is defined, I would suggest create that class as separate class. Otherwise you need to create instance of outer class to access inner class which would be creating instance of Activity and call DatabaseHelper on Activity instance, which is not a good approach in Android.

If you still would like to continue with existing approach, this is how you need to access it:

```
OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

Please read [nested classes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use nested classes, until you are really sure that you need them.
Move DatabaseHelper to separate class-file and import it whenever you need.